# tapestry5-xtensions - does it work with tapestry 5.3?

Tags: java, tapestry

I was trying to integrate [tapestry5-xtensions](https://github.com/xfyre/tapestry5-xtensions) with my application but I receive weird errors, like e.g. this:

```
Unable to locate asset 'classpath:com/xfyre/tapestry5/xtensions/components/blueimp/css/jquery.fileupload.css'
```

I was curious if this library can be integrated with tapestry of version 5.3 which I'm using.

Author seems to upgrade tapestry in this component, but I'm tapestry newbe and don't know if this has influence in application that is using this component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that this does not work with tapestry 5.3 judging by the jquery reference.

Tapestry 5.3 uses [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) as it's 'foundation' javascript framework. Tapestry 5.4 has the ability to choose prototype or jquery as the 'foundation' framework with most, if not all, people choosing jquery over prototype when using Tapestry 5.4.

The [tapestry-jquery](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/) library can retrofit jquery as the 'foundation' framework for tapestry 5.3 but I doubt that tapestry5-xtensions would work with tapestry 5.3 and tapestry-jquery.

Comment: Well for sure this extension pack needs tapestry 5.4 to be compiled. I don't know for sure but I assume that you can't mix components compiled for 5.4 with application compiled in 5.3. So I think you're (unfortunately for me ;) ) right.

Comment: Rather than trying to get a 5.4 library working in 5.3 you should really consider updating your app to 5.4.